# Npp Plugin - Display images inline

Tags: notepad++

Concerning Notepad++ I am searching for a plugin to display image files inline (typical png).

E.g. I would like to display my code like this:
[image]

The original code looks like this:
[image]

Where the image files residing in the same folder than the source file.

*Does somebody knows a plugin doing that?*

The background is having a better GUI than Sikuli built in IDE. The idea of the GUI is great, but coding with npp more productive ;)